# Alternative for Cloud Armor against DDoS attacks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ddos

Is there an alternative way in GCP that emulates or somehow replicates the functionality of Cloud Armor? I'm trying to create a setup that is somehow secured against DDoS but more cost effective as this is only a test run. I'm open to recommendations or if someone can drop a documentation that I can follow would be great as I am new to GCP and I'm still exploring. Many thanks in advance.

Haven't done anything yet and still planning

Comment: Cloud Armor is very inexpensive. What cost problem do you have? Any other solution besides VPC firewall rules will probably have a higher cost because the traffic will reach the endpoint you are trying to protect.

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy third-party DDoS protection solutions

In order to meet your specific needs of protection for DDoS attack prevention/mitigation, consider purchasing specialized third-party DDoS protection solutions to protect against such attacks.

You could easily deploy and manage popular 3rd party DDos tools such as **DDoS radar, FastNetMon Advanced, Imperva Incapsula** from the [Cloud Marketplace](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/marketplace?referrer=search).

You can also refer [refer to Best Practices for DDoS Protection and Mitigation on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf) for additional information.